# Python Folium icon list

Tags: python, folium

Is there any list of icons available that I can use in a expression like I use `home` in this one?

```
folium.Marker(location=[0,20], icon=folium.Icon(color='lightgray', icon='home', prefix='fa')).add_to(m)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can find a full list here:
https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery
use with: `prefix='fa'`

or the glyphicon icons of Bootstrap that are built-in and standard,
thus without prefix needed.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/

Comment: note that folium/leaflet work font-awesome v4. more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58609263/2327328

Comment: How to add the **ad** icon, for example?